# Entity Framework 6.1: Code First navigation properties that do not have corresponding keys defined in database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I am trying the Code First approach with EF 6.1 (I'm very new to it) and I have a weird issue with a navigation property based on a 1.1 or 1.0 relationship in the Database.

I have a User class mapped to a User table that looks like:

```
[Table("TL_MF_SEC_USER_MST")]
public class User
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Table Column : USER_ID
    /// </summary>
    [Key, Column("USER_ID")]
    public decimal ID { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Table Column : USER_CODE
    /// </summary>
    [Column("USER_CODE")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Table Column : DOMAIN_NM
    /// </summary>
    [Column("DOMAIN_NM")]
    public string Domain { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Table Column : EMPLOYEE_ID
    /// </summary>
    [Column("EMPLOYEE_ID")]
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
```

And an Employee class mapped to an Employee table that looks like:

```
[Table("TL_MF_EMPLOYEE_MST")]
public class Employee
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Table Column : EMPLOYEE_CODE
    /// </summary>
    [Key, Column("EMPLOYEE_CODE")]
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Table Column : EMPLOYEE_NAME
    /// </summary>
    [Column("EMPLOYEE_NAME")]
    public string EMPLOYEE_NAME { get; set; }

    public string Manager { get; set; }
```

The problem is that the "Keys" between these tables are the EmployeeID property (not a primary key) from the User class which maps to the EmployeeID property (which is also not a primary or foreign key in the DB) in the Employee class.

Thus, I am trying to create a navigation property on User to Employee but I cannot figure out how to tell EF to use these two non-key fields as the properties to match the user on.

Unfortunately, I am in an environment where I probably can't make significant changes to the actual database schema as this structure is used for administering permissions in at least 8 apps (some of which have 20 plus instances). Some small changes (like adding an index or constraint) might work though.

If there is a way to do this via attributes or fluent api, I would really appreciate a heads up. Any recommendations are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

EF only accepts associations to primary key properties. But it only looks at primary keys defined in the model. So, because of the `Key` attribute on `EmployeeID`, you can use it in associations, like so:

```
public class User
{
    [Key, Column("USER_ID")]
    public decimal ID { get; set; }

    ...

    [Column("EMPLOYEE_ID")]
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }

    public Employee Employee { get; set; } // You need this property
}
```

And in the context's override of `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasRequired(u => u.Employee) // Or HasOptional
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.EmployeeId);
```

Apparently, seeing this `Key` attribute on `EmployeeID`, you are certain that `EmployeeID` is a candidate key to `Employee`. This must be absolutely guaranteed for this to work correctly.

It's clear that you use code-first without migrations. With migrations, this mapping would of course create a primary key `EmployeeId` in the database.

Comment: So the EmployeeID field in the user class can be marked as that User's "Key" aka "Primary Key" even though it is not a primary key in the database. With EF I can only have one "Key" field so I must remove the "Key" attribute from the "ID" field. Also, I would mark the Employee class's EmployeeID as the "Key" for that class even though it isn't a PK or FK in the database. Do I still need to put the User navigation property in the Employee class? and define its relationship back to User somehow? I can't use migrations because I don't have visibility into all the apps that touch these tables.

Comment: You don't need a `User` nav property in `Employee`.

Comment: At this point I still cannot get this to work. I now receive the following error: EasyISAM.DBContexts.User_Employee: : Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'User_Employee_Target' in relationship 'User_Employee'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.
Not sure what I am trying to do is possible as everything else I've read suggests that to map 1:1 in EF you must go PK to PK. Thanks again for your help.